# Bandwidths in Nonparametric Estimation regarding local linear and local constant

Tags: econometrics, nonparametric, semiparametric

I'm reading up on some nonparametric methods and I've gotten a bit confused regarding what will happen given a certain bandwidth. For example, if I consider the local linear least squares method and a local constant least-squares method for which are both provided below. What will happen to both the estimators if the bandwidth h goes to infinity?

[image]
[image]

Both references come from https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/content/1550/regression.html#kernel-regression-on-a-constant

If someone could provide more insight on what happens with h that would be most helpful.

Comment: This is something where you can get a lot of intuition by just fitting some models and plotting the predictions as you increase the bandwidth.

Comment: There is nice animation [here](https://twitter.com/page_eco/status/958687180104245248). Think about the relationship between the bandwidth and width of the black region.